# Python String memory usage on FreeBSD

Tags: python, malloc, freebsd

I'm observing a strange memory usage pattern with python strings on
Freebsd. Consider
the following session. Idea is to create a list which holds some
strings so that cumulative characters in the list is 100MB.

```
l = []
for i in xrange(100000):
    l.append(str(i) * (1000/len(str(i))))
```

This uses around 100MB of memory as expected and 'del l' will clear that.

```
l = []
for i in xrange(20000):
    l.append(str(i) * (5000/len(str(i))))
```

This is using 165MB of memory. I really don't understand where the
additional memory usage is coming from. [Size of both lists are same]

Python 2.6.4 on FreeBSD 7.2. On Linux/windows both uses around
100mb memory only.

Update: I'm measuring memory using 'ps aux'. That can be executed using os.sytem after above code snippets. Also These were executed separately.

Update2: Looks like freebsd mallocs memory in multiples of 2. So allocating 5KB actually allocates 8KB. I'm not sure though.

Comment: What about first executing the second piece of code then executing the first one? I think again it will be 165 MB because this relates to how the operating system / python interpreter and garbage collector manage memory.

Comment: How do you determine the memory it uses?  Are you sure it's correct?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, that would probably be fragments in memory. First of all, memory chunks which are bigger than 255 bytes will be allocated with malloc in CPython. You can reference to

[Improving Python's Memory Allocator](http://evanjones.ca/memoryallocator/)

For performance reason, most of memory allocation, like malloc, will return a aligned address. For example, you will never get a address like

```
0x00003
```

It is not aligned by 4 bytes, it would be very slow for computer to access the memory. Therefore, all address you get by malloc should be

```
0x00000
0x00004
0x00008
```

and so on. The 4 bytes alignment is only the basic common rule, real policy of alignment would be OS variant.

And the memory usage you are talking about should be RSS (not sure).  For most of OS, page size of virtual memory is 4K. For what you allocate, you need 2 page for storing a 5000 byte chunk. Let's see an example for illustrating some memory leak. We assume the alignment is by 256 bytes here.

```
0x00000 {
...       chunk 1
0x01388 }
0x01389 {
...       fragment 1
0x013FF }
0x01400 {
...       chunk 2
0x02788 }
0x02789 {
...       fragment 2
0x027FF }
0x02800 {
...       chunk 3
0x03B88 }
0x03B89 {
...       fragment 3
0x04000 }
```

As you can see there are so many fragments in the memory, they can't be used, but still, they occupy the memory space of a page. I'm not sure what is the alignment policy of FreeBSD, but I think it is caused by reason like this. For using memory efficiently with Python, you can use a big chunk of pre-allocated [bytearray](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#bytearray), and pick a good number as the chunk to use (You have to test to know which number is best, it depends on OS).

Answer (score 0):

The answer may be in [this saga](http://evanjones.ca/python-memory.html). I think that you're witnessing some unavoidable memory manager overhead.

As @Hossein says, try executing both code snippets in one run, and then swap them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that all the memory addresses in freebsd have to be aligned to power of two. So all python's memory pools are somewhat fragmented into the memory and not continuous.

Try to use some other [tool](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/546530/) to spot anything interesting